# Bus Configuration with Autofac: Issue with RabbitMQ vs Loopback?

Tags: rabbitmq, autofac, masstransit

For some reason I can not post to the [masstransit google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/masstransit-discuss), even though I joined, I am told that I do not have permission to post to this group. So I am going to post here...

Now for my problem:

I am using MassTransit v2.7.2, with AutoFac v2.6.3. I am trying to configure Autofac to scan an assembly and register my consumers; all types that implement the IConsumer interface. This seems to work.

I am using the MassTransit.AutofacIntegration assembly and the `LoadFrom(...)` extension method to register the consumers from the container with MassTransit when I configure the bus. Here is the code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
      .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (CreateElectionCommandHandler).Assembly)
      .Where(type => type.Implements<IConsumer>())
      .AsSelf();
var container = builder.Build();

var localBus = ServiceBusFactory.New(configurator =>
                                         {
                                             //configurator.ReceiveFrom("loopback://localhost/testqueue");
                                             configurator.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/commandqueue");
                                             configurator.UseRabbitMq();
                                             configurator.Subscribe(sbc => sbc.LoadFrom(container));
                                         });

Assert.IsTrue(container.IsRegistered<CreateElectionCommandHandler>());
Assert.IsTrue(container.IsRegistered<TerminateElectionCommandHandler>());
Assert.AreEqual(1, localBus.HasSubscription<CreateElection>().Count());
Assert.AreEqual(1, localBus.HasSubscription<TerminateElection>().Count());
```

If I run the above code using the loopback

```
configurator.ReceiveFrom("loopback://localhost/testqueue");
```

configuration (comment out the rabbitmq conifig), the test will pass.

If I comment out the "loopback" config and comment in the

```
 configurator.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/commandqueue");
 configurator.UseRabbitMq();
```

config, the test will fail. (Note: The rabbitmq queue is already up and running - I have been using it as part of my POC). Specifically, it will fail on the assertion:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, localBus.HasSubscription<CreateElection>().Count());
Assert.AreEqual(1, localBus.HasSubscription<TerminateElection>().Count());
```

Can anybody help me understand what is going on here? I am new to MT so fully anticipating that I am missing something, or not configuring something correctly.

Am I correct to assume that if there are no message subscriptions registered, then the bus will not be able to deliver to any of my consumers (even though the consumers are registered)?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: the .AsSelf() style of registration is the way to go, the docs are wrong about the IConsumer version of registering a consumer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With RabbitMQ, subscriptions are not added to the outbound bus until a message is published. This is due to how the classes are inspected and outbound endpoints to the appropriate exchanges are created and added to the pipeline.

So yes, this test will fail with RabbitMQ, but it will in fact work properly when the message is published.

The HasSubscription() calls are really meant for verifying that consumers and such are properly configured using the loopback transport, and really just for vetting out things that are not really integration issues but just making sure the internal MassTransit code is working.

So, if you were to add a Publish() call of one of those types, and *then* call the HasSubscription() extension method, it would pass.

Comment: Apologies - late response due to vacation. Thanks @Chris Patterson for the explanation; adding a call to Publish() on the bus (configured with RabbitMQ) caused the test to pass.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if MassTransit creates an exchange the message types in question. Messages are sent to the exchange and all consumer queues are bound to the exchange. You can look at the Rabbit config to see if that's happened or not as well. And with no consumers registered, no messages will be delivered. Chris has been working on adding options to error is there's consumers so you can handle it in your code.

I would join the mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/masstransit-discuss to get help. There's a lot more people that can ask the right questions to get you where you need to be.

Comment: Then I can easily remove that from my response. Thanks Chris.

Comment: Thanks @Travis - I have actually joined that group, but for some reason I am told that I do not have permissions to post - any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Seems once again Google Groups lost the moderation flag for new users and is just blocking them once they join. I'll try and get this cleaned up.